# How to pause a printer with Get-WMIObject

Tags: powershell

I am looking to create a PowerShell function that perform the same task as the command **Pause Printing**, found in the [Printer](https://i.imgur.com/M1KoHOr.png) menu of the printer "que" dialog window.

Most times I need to completely pause all printing but have incoming print jobs just que up until I toggle **Pause Printing**

While the [PrintManagement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/printmanagement) module offers a lot of useful commands, it lacks this one command.

Searching around, I keep coming across PowerShell [code in this vain](https://gist.github.com/PaulWalkerUK/e991838bd29626ffe60bbe8a0adf593a):

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_Spooler_PrintQueue | Select Name, JobsSpooling, Jobs|where {$_.jobs -gt 0}
(gwmi win32_printer -filter "name='printer_name'").pause()
(gwmi win32_printer -filter "name='printer_name'").resume()
```

On my machine running the first line produces no errors:

```
 Get-WMIObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_Spooler_PrintQueue | Select Name, JobsSpooling, Jobs
 
Name                   JobsSpooling Jobs
----                   ------------ ----
Xerox                             0    2
_Total                            0    2
```

But running `(gwmi win32_printer -filter "name='printer_name'").pause()` after returns an error:

```
gwmi: The term 'gwmi' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
```

I think `gwmi` is an alias of `Get-WMIObject` so I tried `(Get-WmiObject win32_printer -filter "name='printer_name'").pause()` and I get an error:

```
InvalidOperation: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

Even saving the output of the first line to a variable and then running its method:

```
$obj = Get-WMIObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_Spooler_PrintQueue | Select Name, JobsSpooling, Jobs
$obj.pause()
```

Error:

```
InvalidOperation: Method invocation failed because [Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] does not contain a method named 'pause'.
```

Is there a way to actually do this?

---

Edit1:
@Jeff Zeitlin

I named my printer just `zerox` sometime ago when I was setting it up, that is also the name that I pass to `get-printerJob`:

```
 Get-PrintJob -PrinterName xerox

Id    ComputerName    PrinterName     DocumentName         SubmittedTime        JobStatus
--    ------------    -----------     ------------         -------------        ---------
26                    Xerox           xxxxx.txt - Notepad  28/03/2024 17:22:15  Normal
27                    Xerox           xxxxx.txt - Notepad  28/03/2024 17:22:19  Normal
```

Could it be that I need some kind of a technical name (model number or something)? I have no idea, how to about getting this though, I will start looking around anyways.

Comment: The 'null-valued expression error message' strongly suggests that you are not getting a `Win32_Printer` object returned from the `Get-WMIObject` call. Make sure your printer name is correct.

Comment: powershell 5.1?

Comment: (I just tried this on my own print server, and it works fine, _with a valid printer name_.)

Comment: @js2010 Sorry, I should have disclosed this. I am on 7.4.0

Comment: @Ralf_Reddings ps 7 doesn't have get-wmiobject.  You'll have to figure out invoke-cimmethod.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, hey I made an edit to my question, I hope that clarifies things.

Comment: If you're using PowerShell 7dot, rather than Windows PowerShell 5dot, you don't have `Get-WMIObject`; you'll need to use `Get-CIMInstance` and `Invoke-CIMMethod` instead. I think you also need to ensure that the printer names are unique on any given computer.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin got it, thanks for the heads up with the printer names too, it was inevitablly going to pop its head down the line too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using get-ciminstance in powershell 7.  I believe this will work with a real printer.

```
get-ciminstance win32_printer | ? name -eq 'adobe pdf' | 
  invoke-cimmethod -methodname pause

ReturnValue PSComputerName
----------- --------------
          5
```

Comment: This also appears to work against a remote print server if the `-ComputerName` parameter is supplied, and you can also use the `-Filter` parameter to select a specific printer, with the `Get-CIMInstance` cmdlet.

Comment: It does work with real printers; I just tried it.

Comment: `Get-CIMInstance -ComputerName $PrintServer -Class Win32_Printer -Filter "Name = '$PrinterToPause'" | Invoke-CIMMethod -MethodName Pause` did the trick for me.